# Adding to an associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, append

I have an array with three indexes which themselves are arrays:

```
$array['title'];
$array['description'];
$array['link'];
```

I need to add to this array in a loop.

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
 // information is processed, different information on each loop

 $array = $information['processed']; 

}
```

The above works fine when I do it once without the loop, however I cannot add to $array.

What I have tried is:

```
$array = array();
$arraytemp = array();

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
     // information is processed, different information on each loop

     $arraytemp = $information['processed']; 

     $array = $array + $arraytemp; // the unique append as outlined in php manual

    }
```

I have also tried:

```
$array = array();

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
     // information is processed, different information on each loop

     $array[] = $information['processed']; 


    }
```

And I have also tried:

```
$array = array();

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
     // information is processed, different information on each loop

     array_push($array,$information['processed']); 

    }
```

For the application I am developing, I need a way of adding to this array whilst reserving the key structure. So I want to add the new information to the end of the array.

Creating a new dimension by doing something like the following is **not appropriate for my program:**

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
        {
         // information is processed, different information on each loop

         $array[$i] = $information['processed']; 


        }

//The above is not appropriate for my application
```

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you give an example of the end results you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
     $array[$i] = $information['processed']; 
    }
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this without adding the $i index?

Comment: see my edited answer, This way may not be appropriate for my application, I need it without adding a new dimension, if possible. Thanks.